# ZOD [Error]: Schema with id 'Schema' already declared

Tags: typescript, fastify, zod

I am new to Fastify and Typescript. I am working on adding Zod schemas for validation and I am getting this error:

```
/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/schemas.js:32
    throw new FST_ERR_SCH_ALREADY_PRESENT(id)
          ^
FastifyError [Error]: Schema with id 'Schema' already declared!
    at Schemas.add (/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/schemas.js:32:11)
    at SchemaController.add (/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/schema-controller.js:58:30)
    at Object.addSchema (/app/node_modules/fastify/fastify.js:601:29)
    at /app/src/index.ts:23:12
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /app/src/index.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/app/src/index.ts:4:12)
    at main (/app/src/index.ts:32:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.ts:63:1) {
  code: 'FST_ERR_SCH_ALREADY_PRESENT',
  statusCode: 500
```

From Fastify docs:

```
FST_ERR_SCH_ALREADY_PRESENT
A schema with the same $id already exists.
```

I am not sure where eaxctly is this `$id` being set

When I just had one schema and was adding it to fastify in `index.ts` it was working:

```
for (const schema of userSchemas) {
   server.addSchema(schema);
}
```

But adding another schema, throws the above error:

```
for (const schema of [...userSchemas, ...teamSchemas]) {
   server.addSchema(schema);
}
```

`package.json` versions

```
 "fastify": "^4.6.0",
 "fastify-cors": "^6.1.0",
 "fastify-zod": "^1.2.0",
 "zod": "3.19.1",
 "zod-to-json-schema": "^3.18.1"
```

user schema:

```
import { z } from 'zod';
import { buildJsonSchemas } from 'fastify-zod';
import {
  CreateUserRequest,
  UpdateUserRequest,
  UserResponse
} from '../../services/user/interface';

const createUserSchema: z.ZodSchema<CreateUserRequest> = CreateUserRequest;

const updateUserSchema: z.ZodSchema<UpdateUserRequest> = UpdateUserRequest;

const responseUserSchema: z.ZodSchema<UserResponse> = UserResponse;

export const { schemas: userSchemas, $ref } = buildJsonSchemas({
  createUserSchema,
  updateUserSchema,
  responseUserSchema
});
```

team schema

```
import { buildJsonSchemas } from 'fastify-zod';
import { z } from 'zod';
import {
  CreateTeamRequest,
  TeamResponse,
  UpdateTeamRequest
} from '../../services/team/interface';

const createTeamSchema: z.ZodSchema<CreateTeamRequest> = CreateTeamRequest;

const updateTeamSchema: z.ZodSchema<UpdateTeamRequest> = UpdateTeamRequest;

const responseTeamSchema: z.ZodSchema<TeamResponse> = TeamResponse;

export const { schemas: teamSchemas, $ref } = buildJsonSchemas({
  createTeamSchema,
  updateTeamSchema,
  responseTeamSchema
});
```

Looks like it was an issue last year, but has been resolved since: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/2914

Any idea what I maybe be missing here.

EDIT:
console.log(schema) before addSchema gives:

```
{
  '$id': 'Schema',
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    createUserSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    updateUserSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    responseUserSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      additionalProperties: false
    }
  },
  required: [ 'createUserSchema', 'updateUserSchema', 'responseUserSchema' ],
  additionalProperties: false
}
{
  '$id': 'Schema',
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    createTeamSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    updateTeamSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    deleteTeamSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    responseTeamSchema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      additionalProperties: false
    }
  },
  required: [
    'createTeamSchema',
    'updateTeamSchema',
    'deleteTeamSchema',
    'responseTeamSchema'
  ],
  additionalProperties: false
}
```

Comment: I would add a `console.log(schema)` before running the `addSchema`. What does it show?

Comment: Hi @ManuelSpigolon sorry for the late reply, I added the console log above.

Comment: As you can see, both have the `'$id': 'Schema',`. You need to change it

Comment: Yeah, the question is where do I change it? I am not sure, I think I don't set it explicitly anywhere.

Comment: I need to check zod, I don't know how it works, but it is definitely setting those ids

Comment: I have looked into it, but can't find the id setting :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to narrow down the issue to `fastify-zod` By default zod schemas are given the same id i.e `Schema`. So [explicitly adding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-zod) the ids resolved the issue.

For example:

```
import { buildJsonSchemas } from 'fastify-zod';

const { schemas, $ref } = buildJsonSchemas(models, { $id: "MySchema" });
```

Comment: hi do you mind share how you add id explicitly in this answer ? thanks

Comment: Sure, something like this:
const { schemas, $ref } = buildJsonSchemas(models, { $id: "MySchema" });

Comment: got it in the docs thanks!